# Guidance on Achieving 100% Code Coverage in React Native with Jest

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs

I'm writing tests for a React Native app using **Jest**. I've written tests for a specific function, and all the tests for that function have passed. When I check the coverage by running the following command **npx jest --coverage**, I receive the following output.

```
 PASS  __tests__/helpers/HttpHelper.test.tsx                                                                                                
  √ should fetch data and provide a response when the status code is 200 (2 ms)
  √ should throw APIError when the status code is not 200 (1 ms)                                                                            
  √ It should throw an error when any error is caught                                                                                       
                                                                                                                                            
-------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------                                                            
File               | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s                                                             
-------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files          |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 | 
 helpers           |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 | 
  HttpHelper.tsx   |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 | 
 utils             |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
  APIConstants.tsx |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 | 
 utils/AppErrors   |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 | 
  Errors.tsx       |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 | 
-------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       3 passed, 3 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        0.476 s, estimated 1 s
Ran all test suites.
```

However, I have no idea how the coverage report works. What I can see based on the output is that it currently provides coverage based on the **__ test __** folder's test files and the code covered by the functions inside the tests. I want to know if there's a way to have it detect all the application code and provide a report that shows uncovered files. This would help identify files for which we need to write code to achieve 100% code coverage.

and also provide any suggestion and best practices for covering the 100% code coverage in react native apps.

Comment: Jest reports the coverage on tested files. By default runs with `--onlyChanged`, so you can pass ` --watchAll `

Comment: If you have "units" without tests you may want to check [--collectCoverageFrom](https://jestjs.io/docs/cli#--collectcoveragefromglob)

Comment: @Teneff okay got it, so configuring [--collectCoverageFrom](https://jestjs.io/docs/cli#--collectcoveragefromglob) with a list of folder paths, it enables the collection of coverage only from those files.